# Question about fundamental group of complements of divisors

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology

Let $X$ be a quasi-projective smooth algebraic variety (over $\mathbb{C}$) and $D$ an irreducible divisor, such that $(X,D)$ is log smooth.

Is it true that there is an exact sequence $\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow \pi_1(X\setminus D)\rightarrow \pi_1(X)\rightarrow 1$? 
Here, $\mathbb{Z}$ is represents loop around $D$.

I think this should follow by taking a tubular neighborhood and applying Van-Kampen. But on the other hand, this should imply that $\pi_1(\mathbb{P}^2\setminus C)$ is abelian when $C$ is irreducible (after deleting the points from $\mathbb{P}^2$ where $C$ is not snc).
I think this fact is not always true.

Comment: It is true, but not trivial, that the fundamental group of the complement of a nodal curve in $\mathbb{P}^2$ is abelian.